# Python auto random message every xx minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How to send an auto random message every xx minutes to specific server and channel id.

```
async def randommessage():
        response = random.choice(["one", "two", "three"])
        await bot.say(response)
        await asyncio.sleep(120)
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem statement.  Do you want the target channel to be something they pass to a command, or hardcoded, the bot always sending a message to that channel.

Comment: i need bot send a random message from response list to send to a specific channel.

Comment: Yeah, but how are you choosing that channel?  Do you have one in mind right now, or do you want users to trigger this process for arbitrary channels?

Comment: example: i will add a response list `(["one", "two", "three"])`  bot should send a random message to Channeel ID every 5 minutes.

Comment: What channel?  The channel the command is invoked in?  Some specific moderation channel? A channel of the callers choice?

Comment: Channel invoked in. were we used command or by entering channel ID `(id='channel_id_here')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
timeout = 60*5  # 5 minutes

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def randommessage(ctx, *messages):
    while True:
        await bot.say(random.choice(messages))
        await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
```

Here we accept an arbitrary number of arguments as potential messages to echo back to the current channel.  Invocation would look like

```
!randommessage test1 test2 "Messages with spaces go in quotes"
```

A more fully featured version would be

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def randommessage(ctx, channel: discord.Channel, timeout: int, *messages):
    while True:
        await bot.send_message(channel, random.choice(messages))
        await asyncio.sleep(timeout*60)  # timeout minutes
```

Which could be invoked like

```
!randommessages #default 5 test1 test2 "Messages with spaces go in quotes"
```

EDIT:

If you already have the responses from some other mechanism, you can just accept the waiting time and target channel, with reasonable defaults.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def randommessage(ctx, channel: discord.Channel=None, timeout: int=5):
    channel = channel or ctx.message.channel  # default to the channel from the invocation context
    while True:
        await bot.send_message(channel , random.choice(response))
        await asyncio.sleep(timeout*60)  # timeout minutes
```

This assumes the `response` list is available from some encompassing scope.

Comment: Sure.  Instead of accepting messages as a parameter you would just use the list of responses you have.  Without that, it's pretty easy to give everything default arguments as well.

Comment: `ctx.message.server`, though you could also write a command check.